# Azure CI CD build pipeline with gulp for sitecore in Private Agent

Tags: gulp, azure-devops, sitecore, azure-pipelines-build-task

we have Sitecore project with helix principal and using the gulp task we are able to publish the application into local(dev machine) without any issues.

we need to implement the CI/CD with the azure pipeline, added all the task for azure build pipeline like build solution, npm install and gulp task for publish the application,

[Build taks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ch4u.png)

gulp task is: "CI-And-Prepare-Files-CM-CD"

but we are facing the issue while executing the gulp task `because it is being used by another process.`

The error message is as given below.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(96,5):
>   error : Copying file
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll to
>   C:\agent_work\2\s\Deploy\Website\bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
>   failed.  The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\agent_work\2\s\Deploy\Website\bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll'
>   because it is being used by another process.
>   [C:\agent_work\2\s\src\Project\myproject\code\myproject.Site.csproj]

Below is my gulp tasks

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var gutil = require("gulp-util");
var foreach = require("gulp-foreach");
var rimrafDir = require("rimraf");
var rimraf = require("gulp-rimraf");
var runSequence = require("run-sequence");
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var xmlpoke = require("xmlpoke");
//var config = require("./gulpfile.js").config;
var gulpConfig = require("./gulp-config.js")();
var unicorn = require("./scripts/unicorn.js");
var webRootBackup = gulpConfig.webRoot;

var msbuild = require("gulp-msbuild");
var debug = require("gulp-debug");
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var nugetRestore = require('gulp-nuget-restore');
module.exports.config = gulpConfig;

var webTransformationsToBuildFrom = path.resolve("./ConfigsToBuildFrom/Website");
var webCDTransformationsToBuildFrom = path.resolve("./ConfigsToBuildFrom/WebsiteCD");
var dataFolder = path.resolve("./Deploy/Website/Data/App_Data");
var tempWebsite = path.resolve("./Deploy/Website");
var tempWebsiteCD = path.resolve("./Deploy/WebsiteCD");
gulpConfig.webRoot = tempWebsite;


gulp.task("CI-And-Prepare-Files-CM-CD", function (callback) {
    runSequence(
        "CI-Clean",
        "CI-Copy-Configs-CM",
        "CI-Publish",
       // "CI-Copy-Website-CD",
       // "CI-Copy-Configs-CD",
        "CI-Prepare-Files-CM",
       // "CI-Prepare-Files-CD",
        //"CI-Apply-Xml-Transform-CM",
       // "CI-Apply-Xml-Transform-CD",
          "CI-Copy-Items-For-Unicorn",
          "CI-Clean",
        callback);
});

gulp.task("CI-Clean", function (callback) {
    rimrafDir.sync(path.resolve("./Deploy"));
    callback();

});

gulp.task("CI-Copy-Configs-CM", function () {
    return gulp.src(webTransformationsToBuildFrom + "/**")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(tempWebsite));
});

gulp.task("CI-Publish", function (callback) {
    //gulpConfig.webRoot = path.resolve("./");
    gulpConfig.buildConfiguration = "Release";
   // fs.mkdirSync(gulpConfig.webRoot);
    runSequence(
        "Build-Solution",
        "Publish-Foundation-Projects",
        "Publish-Feature-Projects",
        "Publish-Project-Projects",
        callback);
});

gulp.task("CI-Copy-Website-CD", function () {
    return gulp.src(tempWebsite + "/**")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(tempWebsiteCD));
});

gulp.task("CI-Prepare-Files-CM", function (callback) {
    var excludeList = [
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\{Sitecore,Lucene,Newtonsoft,System,Microsoft,Web,Antlr3}*dll",
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\*.pdb",
        tempWebsite + "\\compilerconfig.json.defaults",
        tempWebsite + "\\packages.config",
        tempWebsite + "\\App_Config\\Include\\{Feature,Foundation,Project}\\{z.*DevSettings.config,Website.config}",
        tempWebsite + "\\App_Data\\*",
        tempWebsite + "\\Unicorn\\*",
        "!" + tempWebsite + "\\bin\\Sitecore.Support*dll",    
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\{Sitecore.Foundation.Installer}*",
        tempWebsite + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Foundation\\Foundation.Installer.config",
        tempWebsite + "\\README.md",
        tempWebsite + "\\Web*.config",
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\{App_Config,roslyn,Scripts}",
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\HtmlAgilityPack*dll",
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib*dll",
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection*dll",
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\MongoDB.Driver*dll",
        tempWebsite + "\\bin\\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform*dll"
    ];
    console.log(excludeList);
    return gulp.src(excludeList, { read: false })
               .pipe(clean({ force: true }));
});

gulp.task("CI-Prepare-Files-CD", function (callback) {
    var excludeList = [
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\{Sitecore,Lucene,Newtonsoft,System,Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure}*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\*.pdb",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\compilerconfig.json.defaults",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\packages.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\{Feature,Foundation,Project}\\z.*DevSettings.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Data\\*",
        "!" + tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\Sitecore.Support*dll",
        "!" + tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\Sitecore.{Feature,Foundation,Project}*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\{Sitecore.Foundation.Installer}*",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Rainbow",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Unicorn",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Rainbow*.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Unicorn*.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Foundation\\*.Serialization.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Feature\\*.Serialization.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Project\\*.Serialization.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\DataFolderUnicornMaster.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\App_Config\\Include\\Foundation\\Foundation.Installer.config",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\README.md",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\HtmlAgilityPack*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\MongoDB.Driver*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\Rainbow*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\Unicorn*dll",
        tempWebsiteCD + "\\bin\\Kamsar.WebConsole*dll"
    ];
    console.log(excludeList);

    return gulp.src(excludeList, { read: false }).pipe(rimraf({ force: true }));
});

gulp.task("CI-Copy-Items-For-Unicorn", function () {

    return gulp.src("./Unicorn/**/*.yml")
               .pipe(gulp.dest(dataFolder + "/Unicorn/"));
});

gulp.task("CI-Sync-Unicorn-CM", function (callback) {
    var options = {};
    options.siteHostName = "http://qa.com/";//habitat.getStageUrl()"";
    options.authenticationConfigFile = tempWebsite + "/App_config/Include/Foundation/Unicorn/Unicorn.SharedSecret.config";

    unicorn(function () { return callback() }, options);
});

gulp.task("CI-Build", function (callback) {
    runSequence(
        "CI-Clean",
        "CI-Publish",
        "CI-Prepare-Package-Files",
        "CI-Copy-Items",
        callback);
});

gulp.task("Build-Solution", function () {
    var targets = ["Build"];

    return gulp.src("./" + gulpConfig.solutionName + ".sln")
        .pipe(debug({ title: "NuGet restore:" }))
        .pipe(nugetRestore())
        .pipe(debug({ title: "Building solution:" }))
        .pipe(msbuild({
            targets: targets,
            configuration: gulpConfig.buildConfiguration,
            logCommand: false,
            verbosity: "minimal",
            stdout: true,
            errorOnFail: true,
            maxcpucount: 0,
            toolsVersion: gulpConfig.MSBuildToolsVersion
        }));
});

gulp.task("CI-Copy-Items", function () {
    return gulp.src("./Unicorn/Configurations/**/*.yml")
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./Output/Data/Unicorn/'));
});

gulp.task("CI-Prepare-Package-Files", function (callback) {
    var excludeList = [
        gulpConfig.webRoot + "\\bin\\{Sitecore,Lucene,Newtonsoft,System,Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure}*dll",
        gulpConfig.webRoot + "\\compilerconfig.json.defaults",
        gulpConfig.webRoot + "\\packages.config",
        gulpConfig.webRoot + "\\App_Config\\Include\\{Feature,Foundation,Project}\\z.*DevSettings.config",
        "!" + gulpConfig.webRoot + "\\bin\\Sitecore.Support*dll",
        "!" + gulpConfig.webRoot + "\\bin\\Sitecore.{Feature,Foundation,Habitat,Demo,Common}*dll"
    ];
    console.log(excludeList);

    return gulp.src(excludeList, { read: false }).pipe(rimraf({ force: true }));
});

var cleanProjectFiles = function (layerName) {
    const filesToDelete = [
        '.\\src\\'+layerName+'\\Core\\code\\obj\\Dev\\Package\\PackageTmp\\bin\\Sitecore*',
        '.\\src\\'+layerName+'\\Core\\code\\obj\\Dev\\Package\\PackageTmp\\bin\\roslyn*'
    ];
    console.log("Removing " + layerName + " configs/binaries");
    return gulp.src(filesToDelete, { read: false })
        .pipe(debug({ title: "====================Cleaning Projects================" }))
        .pipe(clean({ force: true }));
};

var publishProjects = function (location, dest) {
    dest = dest || gulpConfig.webRoot;
    var targets = ["Clean","Build"];

    console.log("publish to " + dest + " folder");
    return gulp.src([location + "/**/code/*.csproj"])
        .pipe(foreach(function (stream) {
            return stream
                .pipe(debug({ title: "Building project:" + stream}))
                .pipe(msbuild({
                    targets: targets,
                    configuration: gulpConfig.buildConfiguration,
                    logCommand: false,
                    verbosity: "minimal",
                    stdout: true,
                    errorOnFail: true,
                    maxcpucount: 0,
                    toolsVersion: gulpConfig.MSBuildToolsVersion,
                    properties: {
                        Platform: "AnyCpu",
                        DeployOnBuild: "true",
                        DeployDefaultTarget: "WebPublish",
                        WebPublishMethod: "FileSystem",
                        BuildProjectReferences: "false",
                        DeleteExistingFiles: "false",
                        publishUrl: dest,
                    }
                }));
        }));
};

gulp.task("Publish-Foundation-Projects", function () {

        publishProjects("./src/Foundation"),
        cleanProjectFiles("Foundation");
});

gulp.task("Publish-Feature-Projects", function () {

        publishProjects("./src/Feature"),
         cleanProjectFiles("Feature");
});

gulp.task("Publish-Project-Projects", function () {

        publishProjects("./src/Project"),
         cleanProjectFiles("Project");
});
```

Comment: What is the issue? did you get an error?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(96,5): error : Copying file obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll to C:\agent\_work\2\s\Deploy\Website\bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll failed. The process cannot access the file 'C:\agent\_work\2\s\Deploy\Website\bin\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll' because it is being used by another process. [C:\agent\_work\2\s\src\Project\code\project.Site.csproj]